# Image resize issue with PaperClip and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip, ruby-1.9.3

Having terrible trouble with my application image rendering since an upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.1.0.rc4 and Paperclip 3.4.0.

No matter what variation of settings I give Paperclip the infile linked to below comes out *blurred* as is shown by the linked outfile.

The outfile must fit into a box of 620x412 [as shown here](http://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-to-rent/property-25482672.html).

[Link to input file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9sM1xgTybOWNFpwVnkzdTZKSUk/edit?usp=sharing)

[Link to output file this code generates](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9sM1xgTybOWS01EQy14Q2I3R3M/edit?usp=sharing)

The full code for the model is below ...

```
class Propertyimage < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :property

  validates_presence_of :description
  validates_presence_of :sortorder

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :export => {:geometry => "620x412#", :quality =>    100, :format => 'JPG'} },
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
  :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and was able to fix after a lot of trial and error using three criteria: image size specification, convert_options, and scaling the image.  For example, in your Propertyimage class try:

```
has_attached_file :image, 
  :styles => { :original => ["640x480", :jpg], :export => {:geometry => "620x412#", :quality => 100, :format => 'JPG'} },
  :convert_options => { :all => "-quality 100" },
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
  :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
```

Then you can play with the sizes of your image tag, or as in my case using a PDF, Id used the scale option:

```
pdf.image the_file_name, :at => [0, 720], :scale => 0.75
```